# There are known knowns

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

Former US Secretary of Defense, Donald Rumsfeld, [famously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns) popularized the phrase "known knowns." Here we're going to distill his remarks into a four-line stanza.

Specifically, output this text:

```
known knowns
known unknowns
unknown knowns
unknown unknowns
```

Capitalization doesn't matter (for example, `Known unKnowns` is fine), and a single trailing newline is acceptable, but no other formatting changes are allowed. That means a single space between the words, and either `LF` (59 bytes) or `CR/LF` (62 bytes) between the lines.

#### Rules

- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this has got so many downvotes? For me it is a reasonable challenge and has encouraged a variety of answers in a mixture of languages.

Comment: @ElPedro The reason behind the many downvotes is a known unknown

Comment: May we return a matrix or a list of strings?

Comment: @Adám A list of four strings would be OK, as that's still preserving the space between words; but, unless you're doing a matrix of every character including the spaces, matrices are not OK.

Comment: [Related](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/216394-the-phrase-in-the-dark-as-i-m-sure-you-know) :^D

Comment: Are the trailing spaces intentional?

Comment: @user202729 There aren't any trailing spaces.

Comment: I don't think Rumsfeld ever said "unknown knowns", although others have extended it as "things we know but refuse to acknowledge"

Answer (score 30):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>54</s> 52 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to xnor</sup>

```python
k='unknowns'
for i in 8,6,2,0:print k[i/3:7],k[i%3:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9tWvTQvOy@/PK9YnSstv0ghUyEzT8FCx0zHSMfAqqAoM69EITs6U9/YyjxWB8hQNbaK/f8fAA)

The results from the `/` and `%` will be `[[2, 2], [2, 0], [0, 2], [0, 0]]` that will be the starting indexes, removing the `un` when `2`, keeping the string unaltered when `0`

Comment: If you let `k` be `'unknowns'`, you can correct with `k[i/3:7]` and save two bytes.

Answer (score 28):

## Vim <s>28</s> 25 bytes

This is my first Vim answer, any golfing tips are welcome.

```
2iunknown ␛rsY3P2xw.+.jw.
```

[image: In action]

Thank you [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn) for writing the [python script](https://gist.github.com/lynn/5f4f532ae1b87068049a23f7d88581c5) to make that fantastic animation.

This can also be run by V [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3yizNC87L788T0G6qDjSOMCoIlxPWy8rXO//fwA)

Also 25:

```
2iknown ␛rsY3pwiun␛+.+.w.
```

Comment: I only managed to find another 25: `2iunknown ␛rsYPw2x2YP2xj.` or a slight variation `2iunknown ␛rsYPw2x2YPⓋjlx` (Ⓥ = Ctrl-V).

Comment: @Lynn Nice, I tried Ctrl-V but got something longer.

Answer (score 23):

## bash, 36 bytes

```
printf %s\\n {,un}known\ {,un}knowns
```

other solutions

36

```
eval echo\ {,un}known\ {,un}knowns\;
```

37

```
eval printf '%s\\n' \{,un}known{\\,s}
```

38

```
eval eval echo\\ \{,un}known{\\,'s\;'}
```

41

```
x=\\\ {,un}known;eval "eval echo$x$x\s\;"
```

45

```
x='\ {,un}known' e=eval;$e "$e echo$x$x\s\;"
x='\ {,un}known' e=eval\ ;$e"$e\echo$x$x\s\;"
```

if leading newline and extra space were accepted  31 bytes :

```
echo '
'{,un}known\ {,un}knowns
```

Comment: for those wondering what kind of sorcery is this (like myself): this is [bash brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)

Comment: … even better explained on [bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace), and you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUG1OCYmT6FapzSvNjsvvzwvBold/P8/AA "Bash – Try It Online").

Comment: If in doubt, put the whole answer in a code block

Comment: reworded, the invalid input at the end

Answer (score 14):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Erik the Outgolfer* (avoid closing string)

```
„Š¢—‚#D's«â»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v8wNWFiMWX//@KAnsWgwqLigJTigJojRCdzwqvDosK7//8)

**Explanation**

```
„Š¢—‚           # push the string "known unknown"
     #          # split on spaces
      D         # duplicate
       's«      # append "s" to each
          â     # cartesian product
           »    # join on newline
```

Comment: `“Š¢—‚“` -> `„Š¢—‚`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Oh yeah, only 2 words. Thanks!

Comment: Bahhh... why didn't I look first? Same answer.

Answer (score 11):

### CJam (<strike>26</strike> 25 bytes)

```
"unknown"_2>\]2m*{S*'sN}%
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22unknown%22_2%3E%5C%5D2m*%7BS*'sN%7D%25)

Cartesian product of `["known" "unknown"]` with itself, then each element joined with space and suffixed with `s` and a newline.

Thanks to [Erik](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer) for a one-byte saving.

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>52</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```r
cat(gsub(1,"known","1 1s
1 un1s
un1 1s
un1 un1s"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCO9uDRJw1BHKTsvvzxPSUfJUMGwmMtQoTQPSAEJBSgF4itpav7/DwA)

Surprisingly short substitution and print commands make this an *actually competitive* R answer in a [string](/questions/tagged/string) challenge!

<s>Even if it's super boring.</s> Mildly more interesting now, and with a byte saved thanks to [J.Doe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81549/j-doe)!

Saved another byte thanks to [this answer, also by J.Doe!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173971/67312)

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>60</s> <s>58</s> <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```hs
f<$>l<*>l
f x y=x++' ':y++"s"
l=["known","unknown"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfk1lcomCrEPM/zUbFLsdGyy6HK02hQqHStkJbW11B3apSW1upWIkrxzZaKTsvvzxPSUepNA/Civ2fm5iZB9Scm1jgq1BQWhJcUuSTpwAy8f@/5LScxPTi/7rJBQUA)

Yields a list of lines as was recently allowed. Thanks to [@firefrorefiddle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7508/firefrorefiddle) for pointing out.

-2 bytes thanks to [cole](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42833/cole).

---

**58 byte version:**

```hs
f=<<"? ?s\n? un?s\nun? ?s\nun? un?s"
f '?'="known"
f c=[c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfXFKUmZeuYKsQ8z/N1sZGyV7Bvjgmz16hNA9EA0kFGA0SUeJKU1C3V7dVys7LL88D8ZJto5Nj/@cmZuYBzSgoLQkuKVKAmPn/X3JaTmJ68X/d5IICAA) Yields a single string.

Comment: Your 60 byte version is actually a 53 byte version because you can remove `unlines` because "A list of four strings would be OK, as that's still preserving the space between words;" (Comment to original question).

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfk1lcomCrEPM/zUbFLsdGyy6HK02hQqHStkJbW11B3apSW1upWIkrxzZaKTsvvzxPSUepNA/Civ2fm5iZB9Scm1jgq1BQWhJcUuSTpwAy8f@/5LScxPTi/7rJBQUA) combining your approach with @PeterTaylor's

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

*Saved 1 byte using an intermediate printing approach from Leo.*

```
 ¶u

knowns
u
 un
:`s 
 
m`^
un
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fS@HQtlIuruy8/PK8Yq5SLoXSPC6rhGIFLgWu3IQ4rtK8//8B)

#### Explanation

```
 ¶u
```

Turns the non-existent (i.e. empty) input into the string on the second line. That one seems pretty weird, but these characters are codes for the stuff that goes *between* two instances of `known[s]` on the first two lines of the result. Space and linefeed are just themselves and `u` is  `un`.

```
knowns
```

Now we insert `knowns` at every position (i.e. at the beginning, end, and between every pair of characters).

```
u
 un
```

We decode the `u`.

```
:s
```

Then we get rid of the `s`s in front of spaces, i.e. those in the first half of each line, and print the result.

```
m`^
un
```

And finally we prepend `un` to both lines and print the result again.

This beats [the trivial approach](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fK1shu/jQtmyF0jwQDSQVYDRIhCubKzsvvzzv/38A) of just using a placeholder for `known` by 4 bytes, but not [Neil's more efficient implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145453/52210) of that approach.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
 s¶ uns¶un s¶un uns
 |s
known$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fS6H40DaF0jwgWZqnACGBPC6FmmKu7Lz88jwVtf//AQ) Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @ovs. Explanation: This is almost the trivial approach of using a placeholder for `known`, except here I simply insert it before each space or `s`, which saves <s>3</s> 4 bytes.

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fS6H40DaF0jwgWZqnACGBPC6FmmKu7Lz88jwVtf//AQ)

Comment: You can improve this by [printing halfway](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fS6H40DaF0rxiLqsEhZpiruy8/PI8FTUu1YQ4rtK8//8B)

Comment: @Leo using that you don't even need the `|s` approach any more: https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fK1shu/jQtmyF0rzsYi6rhGyu7Lz88jyu3IQ4rtK8//8B

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 54 bytes

```cs
v=>@"z zs
z unzs
unz zs
unz unzs".Replace("z","known")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xDsIgFAB3voIwQVL7A7WNiYmTLjo4I74YIj5IH9RI02/HGlnuctMZ2hg/Qgnp5qzhxmkivp8ZRR3Xvnwowqs9JDRbiqPFR/PXEPoy9cNOZJ6JZZ5w1Qpe9WvRniE4bUCKLBrxRP9GoUrH6qw@Jm/v/KQtSsXmOtx7JO@gvY42wtEiyCAxOadUxxa2lC8)

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <s>55 51</s> 47 bytes

```php
<?=strtr("1 1s
1 01s
01 1s
01 01s",[un,known]);
```

[try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/721dcb4227f413507aae5f582e8de8c2284983eb)

Comment: Do you need opening tags for php entries?

Comment: @Josiah I need something to print the result; `<?=` is the shortest option.

Answer (score 5):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), <s>1021</s> <s>1012</s> 993 bytes

*-19 bytes thanks to Joe King!*

```
,.Ajax,.Ford,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Exeunt][Enter Ajax and Ford]Ajax:Am I nicer a big cat?If sois the remainder of the quotient betweenI the sum ofa cat a big cat worse a big cat?If notlet usScene V.You be the sum ofa fat fat fat pig the cube ofthe sum ofa cat a big big cat.Speak thy.You be the sum ofyou the sum ofa cat a fat fat fat pig.Speak thy.Scene V:.[Exit Ajax][Enter Page]Page:You be the product ofthe sum ofa cat a big big cat the sum ofa pig a big big big big cat.Speak thy.You be the sum ofyou the sum ofa cat a big cat.Speak thy.Ford:You be the sum ofI a cat.Speak thy.You be the sum ofyou a big big big cat.Speak thy.Page:Speak thy.You be the sum ofyou the sum ofa cat a big big cat.Is the remainder of the quotient betweenAjax a big cat worse a cat?If soyou big big big big big cat.Speak thy.If solet usScene X.You be twice the sum ofa cat a big big cat.Speak thy.Scene X:.[Exit Page][Enter Ajax]Ford:You be the sum ofyou a cat.Be you worse a big big big cat?If solet usAct I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVNBboMwEPzKPgD5AVyiVEol3ypFqlpFHBxYUtpgE2yL5PXUayAxcdSi9gDCu57Z8TDWzbHvE7b@FOeEPau2SNiLOKCr5AZ4yrY5SqSP3eaMVppst5EGWyAACFkAYTJapesaOMgqd10B@@oAuTArXoJWlQbzgdBiLSpZuL4qfeFklalQGtij6RAl91Vta7dBEPxGBJ1qNc6JpTJHNGD1IPKVvSvrqGYkpYNOT@Og1Mut26TKx7NGfrZtUHy57ZeY9eIKMfhuUkAwyvMeVsZbN9lIXmf0SoMpTasK6@z/ReJMA53t1v3XQWIg/eM0QnMQSwaIHxT5k/9J4MTFF0ZryGuUpmtEadK9e7FevzXM3NtVc@eCD0sjNYKnRPgUBBcre2z44CYxPSHQIrwTwaBVINNfY9b33w)

Comment: You cam remove the spaces after some multi-word operators like `the sum of`

Comment: Really? Huh, that's a lot of shortest-representations-of-numbers I have to recalculate. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>64</s> <s>47</s> 35 bytes

```apl
⍪,∘.{⍺,' ',⍵,'s'}⍨k('un',k←'known')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtEx71rtJ51DFDr/pR7y4ddQV1nUe9W3XUi9VrH/WuyNZQL81T18kGKlPPzssvz1PX/P8fAA)

**How?**

`k←'known'` - `k` is `"known"`

`k('un',k←'known')` - `"known" "unknown"`

`∘.`...`⍨` - outer product with itself

`{⍺,' ',⍵,'s'}` - with the function that formats the args as `{⍺} {⍵}s`

`,` - smash the product table into vector

`⍪` - separate to columns

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HHDL3qR31TH7VNeNS7S0ddQV3nUe9WHfVi9dpHvSt0gNLq2Xn55Xnqh1Y86l2jXpqn/v8/AA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") (+ fixing the bad output format)

Comment: @dzaima [31](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HHDL3qR31TH7VNeNTR9ah3l7qC@qPererF6rWPelfoAKXVs/Pyy/PUD6141LtGvTRP/f9/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## C (gcc),  <s>79</s>   <s>78</s>  76 bytes

*Thanks to @Justin Mariner for golfing one byte!*

```
f(){printf("%s %1$ss\n%1$s un%1$ss\nun%1$s %1$ss\nun%1$s un%1$ss","known");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0m1WEHVUKW4OCYPRCmU5kF5EIYCKg8qq6SjlJ2XX56npGld@x9ojEJuYmaehiZXNZcCEABNt@aq/Q8A)

Comment: I think this can be one byte less if you use `%1$s` and get rid of `i`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0nVUKVYAUQUx@SB2aV5UB6EoYDKg8oq6Shl5@WX5ylpWtf@BxqkkJuYmaehyVXNpQAEQPOtuWr/AwA)

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```java
v->" s\n uns\nun s\nun uns".replaceAll(" |s","known$0")
```

-1 byte thanks to *@SuperChafouin*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LY7BCsIwEETvfsUQPKRgi/ei4AfYi@BFPcQ0Smq6LU1SEe231y0t7A7MLryZSvUqbVpDVfkatVPe46gsfVeApWC6h9IGxWSBU@gsPaHlubEl@iTn68DL44MKVqMAYYexT/cC/kqIxBoJs7ITWWdax8yDc1Lg58VGvKh503orkjGfYW28O4YtzH4Kq7mTnPMvN6hkKfTxwdRZE0PW8is4kpRpSdG5ZGk3jH8)

```java
v->                         // Method with empty unused parameter
  " s\n uns\nun s\nun uns"  //  Literal String
   .replaceAll(" |s",       //  Replace all spaces and "s" with:
     "known                 //   Literal "known"
           $0")             //   + the match (the space or "s")
                            // End of method (implicit / single-line return-statement)
```

Comment: Okay, I gotta ask... why `\r`? ^^'

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Woops.. ;p

Comment: You can win one byte with `v->" s\n uns\nun s\nun uns".replaceAll(" |s","known$0")`

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 45 bytes

```perl6
$_='known';.say for [X](($_,"un$_")xx 2)X~'s'
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/18l3lY9Oy@/PE/dWq84sVIhLb9IIToiVkNDJV5HqTRPJV5Js6JCwUgzok69WP3/fwA)

### Expanded

```perl6
$_ = 'known';

.say                # print with trailing newline the value in topic variable ｢$_｣

  for               # do that for each of the following

    [X](
      ($_, "un$_")  # ('known','unknown')
        xx 2        # list repeated twice
    ) X~ 's'        # cross using &infix:«~» with 's' (adds ｢s｣ to the end)
```

The `[X](…)` part generates

```perl6
(("known","known"),("known","unknown"),("unknown","known"),("unknown","unknown")).Seq
```

Then using `X~` on it coerces the inner lists into a Str (because of the `&infix:«~»` operator), which doing so adds a space between values.

```perl6
("known known", "known unknown", "unknown known", "unknown unknown").Seq
```

Then each is joined with an `s`

```perl6
("known knowns", "known unknowns", "unknown knowns", "unknown unknowns").Seq
```

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/18jOiJWQ0Ml3lY9Oy@/PE9dR6k0TyVeSbOiQsFIM6JOvVhd085Orzix8v9/AA "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>57</s> 52 bytes

```
id=<<id=<<mapM(\s->[s,"un"++s])["known ","knowns\n"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPzPF1sYGTOQmFvhqxBTr2kUX6yiV5ilpaxfHakYrZefll@cpKOlAGMUxeUqx/3MTM/MUbBUKSkuCS4oU0v7/S07LSUwv/q@bXFAAAA)

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcpBDkAwEADAr2w2DgQ/wAs4OarDplFErcZW/N6KuM1hFpJt8l5dbdQebClWSbNT6FIjZTNIgRdjnsuYDbjxcTNg8UNw1J1Whhq@D@GKfTxbBqePdZ5m0dKG8AI) with an alternate output of list

Comment: @cole: the output format is very strict, so I think a list of strings in not valid.

Comment: the other haskell answer does it, seems like the OP okayed that format.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
“ṿ1“ŒwƘ»pż€⁾ sY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/cbAqmjk8qPzTi0u@DonkdNax417lMojvz/HwA)

Comment: :( The compressed version is 29 bytes

Answer (score 3):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 33 bytes

**Disclaimer**: I didn't realise that brace expansion was possible within the `<...>` operator (learned thanks to @[Grimy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6484/grimy)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146295/9365)!) and the using the clever expansion trick from @[NahuelFouilleul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70745/nahuel-fouilleul)'s [amazing bash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145456/9365), I was able to build this solution. I will happily remove this at either of their request.

```perl
print<"{,un}known {,un}knowns$/">
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvxEapWqc0rzY7L788TwHBLFbRV7L7/x8A)

---

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 42 bytes

**41 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```perl
s//K Ks
K unKs/;s/K/known/g;$\=s/^/un/gmr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX99bwbuYy1uhNM@7WN@6WN9bPzsvvzxPP91aJca2WD9OvxTIzi36/5/rX35BSWZ@XvF/3QIA)

---

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 45 bytes

Tried to come up with an alternative, but couldn't make it shorter... Thought it was different enough to warrant adding anyway.

```perl
print"un"x/[3467]/,known,$_%2?"s
":$"for 0..7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRKk0T6lCP9rYxMw8Vl8nOy@/PE9HJV7VyF6pmEvJSkUpLb9IwUBPz/z/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>53</s> 50 bytes

```
$><<"a as
a unas
una as
una unas".gsub(?a,"known")
```

Comment: Replace `\n` with a literal newline.

Comment: @ValueInk Done.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
OΠṠemhw¨ṅW∫ḟωμ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr//9PzqDhuaBlbWh3wqjhuYVX4oir4bifz4nOvP//)

## Explanation

```
OΠṠemhw¨ṅW∫ḟωμ
       ¨ṅW∫ḟωμ    The compressed string "knowns unknowns"
      w           Split on spaces ["knowns","unknowns"]
   e              Make a list with:
    mh             this list with the last letter dropped from each word
  Ṡ                and this same list
                  [["known","unknown"],["knowns","unknowns"]]
 Π                Cartesian product [["known","knowns"],["unknown","knowns"],["known","unknowns"],["unknown","unknowns"]]
O                 Sort the list [["known","knowns"],["known","unknowns"],["unknown","knowns"],["unknown","unknowns"]]
                  Implicitely print joining with spaces and newlines
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>71</s> <s>66</s> <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```
(<*>).map((++).init)<*>map(' ':)$["knowns","unknowns"]
```

Thanks to [@Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393/leo) for -3 bytes!

<sub>Note: In the question's comments, the o.p. said that returning a list of strings is okay</sub>

[Try it here.](https://repl.it/MjyA/2)

Comment: This is great and I can't even understand it, but the part from your second `fmap` onwards can be shortened to `map(' ':)` :)

Comment: @Leo Thanks! Haha, I'm not even sure I understand it anymore

Comment: No need to give the function a name, so you can drop the `f=`.

Answer (score 3):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), 48 bytes

```
00 C0 A9 37 85 FB A9 73 4D 2B C0 8D 2B C0 A9 0D 4D 2C C0 8D 2C C0 A9 26 90 02
E9 02 A0 C0 20 1E AB 06 FB D0 E1 60 55 4E 4B 4E 4F 57 4E 53 0D 00
```

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B%22controlPort2%22:%22joystick%22,%22primaryControlPort%22:2,%22keys%22:%7B%22SPACE%22:%22%22,%22RETURN%22:%22%22,%22F1%22:%22%22,%22F3%22:%22%22,%22F5%22:%22%22,%22F7%22:%22%22%7D,%22files%22:%7B%22know.prg%22:%22data:;base64,AMCpN4X7qXNNK8CNK8CpDU0swI0swKkmkALpAqDAIB6rBvvQ4WBVTktOT1dOUw0A%22%7D,%22vice%22:%7B%22-autostart%22:%22know.prg%22%7D%7D)**

**Usage:** `sys49152`

---

#### How it works

The trick here is to use a "loop counter" for 8 iterations where bits 7 to 1 of the initial value are `1` for `unknown(s)` and `0` for `known(s)` in one iteration. This counter is shifted to the left after each iteration (shifting the leftmost bit into the carry flag) and bit `0` is initially `1` so we know we're finished once the last bit was shifted out. In the first iteration, `known` is printed because when calling the program, the carry flag is clear.

In each iteration, the end of the string is toggled between `<space>` and `s<newline>`.

Here's the commented disassembly listing:

```
         00 C0            .WORD $C000    ; load address
.C:c000  A9 37            LDA #$37       ; initialize loop counter ...
.C:c002  85 FB            STA $FB        ; ... as 0011 0111, see description
.C:c004   .loop:
.C:c004  A9 73            LDA #('s'^' ') ; toggle between 's' and space
.C:c006  4D 2B C0         EOR .plural
.C:c009  8D 2B C0         STA .plural
.C:c00c  A9 0D            LDA #$0D       ; toggle between newline and 0
.C:c00e  4D 2C C0         EOR .newline
.C:c011  8D 2C C0         STA .newline
.C:c014  A9 26            LDA #<.knowns  ; start at "known" except
.C:c016  90 02            BCC .noprefix  ; when carry set from shifting $fb:
.C:c018  E9 02            SBC #$02       ; than start at "un"
.C:c01a   .noprefix:
.C:c01a  A0 C0            LDY #>.knowns  ; high-byte of string start
.C:c01c  20 1E AB         JSR $AB1E      ; output 0-terminated string
.C:c01f  06 FB            ASL $FB        ; shift loop counter
.C:c021  D0 E1            BNE .loop      ; repeat if not 0 yet
.C:c023  60               RTS            ; done
.C:c024   .unknowns:
.C:c024  55 4E           .BYTE "un"
.C:c026   .knowns:
.C:c026  4B 4E 4F 57 4E  .BYTE "known"
.C:c02b   .plural:
.C:c02b  53              .BYTE "s"
.C:c02c   .newline
.C:c02c  0D 00           .BYTE $0d, $00
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 66 bytes

```
@set s= in (known unknown)do @
@for %%a%s%for %%b%s%echo %%a %%bs
```

Alternative answer, also 66 bytes:

```
@for %%a in (k unk)do @for %%b in (k unk) do @echo %%anown %%bnowns
```

Comment: Of course, nested loops, haven't thought of that... good job!

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```sql
PRINT REPLACE('1 1s
1 un1s
un1 1s
un1 un1s',1,'known')
```

SQL supports line breaks inside string literals, so similar to some other languages already posted.

**EDIT**: Slightly longer (**82 bytes**), but a bit more clever:

```sql
SELECT k+s+k+p+k+s+u+p+u+s+k+p+u+s+u+p
FROM(SELECT'known'k,' 's,'unknown'u,'s
'p)t
```

**EDIT 2**: My favorite so far, using a cross-self-join from a derived table (**79 bytes**):

```sql
WITH t AS(SELECT'known'a UNION SELECT'unknown')
SELECT z.a+' '+t.a+'s'FROM t,t z
```

**EDIT 3**: Changed the replacement character from `'x'` to `1`, which lets me remove the quotes around it and save 2 bytes, since `REPLACE` does an implicit conversion to string.

Answer (score 2):

## Haxe, 71 bytes

```
(?x)->[for(a in x=["","un"])for(b in x)a+'known ${b}knowns'].join("\n")
```

[Try it online!](http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#7c670)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```powershell
' s
 uns
un s
un uns'-replace' |s','known$&'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X12hmEuhNK@YqzRPAUwA2eq6RakFOYnJqeoKNcXqOurZefnleSpq6v//AwA)

(Almost) simple string replacement. Uses [Neil's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145453/8478) to trim two bytes. Thanks to Martin for pointing that out.

Sadly, it's shorter than the more interesting cross-product method by <s>three</s> <s>five</s> three bytes:

### [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```powershell
($a='known','unknown')|%{$i=$_;$a|%{"$i $_`s"}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0Ml0VY9Oy@/PE9dR700D8LSrFGtVsm0VYm3VkkEMpVUMhVU4hOKlWpr//8HAA)

Comment: [Neil's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145453/8478) saves [2 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X12hmEuhNK@YqzRPAUwA2eq6RakFOYnJqeoKNcXqOurZefnleSpq6v//AwA).

Comment: @MartinEnder Right, good call. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 47 bytes

```
"K Ks
K unKs
unK Ks
unK unKs"|gsub("K";"known")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/1/JW8G7mMtboTQPSAEJBSgF4ivVpBeXJmkoeStZK2Xn5ZfnKWn@//8vv6AkMz@v@L@ubl5pTo5uZl5BaQmQU5RYrptfWgLkAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript <s>66 54 53</s> 50 bytes

```
_=>` s
 uns
un s
un uns`.replace(/ |s/g,'known$&')
```

#### History

- saved 12 bytes thanks to @someone (explicit usage of "un" in the main string)
- saved 1 byte thanks to @ThePirateBay (split..join instead of replace)
- saved 3 bytes thanks to @Neil (better replace())

Comment: I think it would be shorter to add un in the string itself

Comment: you're totally right, a shame that it dumbs the solution so much down though.

Comment: Is the space after the comma needed?

Comment: nope, just noticed that too.

Comment: BTW I think you can save 4 bytes by porting my Retina answer.

Comment: Using [split..join](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b5a5350457616afd6eedd8c7fd39f753) instead of `replace` saves one byte.

Comment: @Neil i have no idea about Retina at all

Comment: I meant by removing the `0`s and using `.replace(/ |s/g,'known$&')` (which now only saves 3 bytes).

Comment: interesting, editting the answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 38 bytes

```
a/known/a as\na unas\nuna as\nuna unas
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/P1E/Oy@/PE8/USGxOCYvUaE0D0QDSQUYDRL5/x8A)

Comment: I'm seeing this language for the first time, but `a/known / z/s\n/aazaunazunaazunaunaz` seems to work for 36 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>60</s> <s>57</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```bash
b=${a=known}s;echo "$a $b
$a un$b
un$a $b
un$a un$b"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P8lWpTrRNjsvvzyvttg6NTkjX0FJJVFBJYkLSJbmAWkgAeaDaZCI0v//AA)

- L3viathan: -3
- Dom Hastings: -3
- manatwork: -2

Thank you guys!

Comment: 57 bytes if you replace the "\n" with a literal newline

Comment: @L3viathan 54 even, as you won't need the `-e` after `echo`! :)

Comment: `a=known;b=${a}s` → `b=${a=known}`

Comment: @manatwork you meant `b=${a=known}s`, but I got it – thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 28 keystrokes

```
iknown <C-n>s<CR><C-X><C-l><S-Left>un<Esc>o<C-p><Left> <C-n><Esc>o<C-p><C-p> <C-p>s
```

Also 28:

```
iknown <C-n>s<Esc>qqo<C-X><C-l><S-Left>un<Esc>qo<C-p><Left> <C-n><Esc>@q
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>70</s> 66 bytes

Thanks to @l4m2 for -4 bytes!

```c
f(i){for(i=8;i--;)printf("unknown%s"+(i>4|i==2)*2,i%2?" ":"s\n");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPT1sI6U1fXWrOgKDOvJE1DqTQvOy@/PE@1WElbI9POpCbT1tZIU8tIJ1PVyF5JQclKqTgmT0nTuvY/ULlCbmJmngbQIA2QAAA)

Comment: In reverse `f(i){for(i=8;i--;)printf("unknown%s"+(i>4|i==2)*2,i%2?" ":"s\n");}`

Comment: Suggest `L"ੳ "+i%2` instead of `i%2?" ":"s\n"`

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 49 bytes

```hs
unwords<$>mapM(\s->[s,"un"++s])["known","knowns"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpLDkAwEADQqzQTC1JugBOwssSiqW86RmM0vb0RsXqbtxl2M6JgNUigeF4Tl0l9GN@mAxd1zzkEAq15zHpwdEaC/JdhlMPspCr1deXD3d1XQwrlsQualaWw3r8)

Answer (score 1):

## C, gcc, 64 bytes

```
c="unknown";f(i){for(i=4;i--;)printf("%s %ss\n",i&2|c,i%2*2+c);}
```

Seems doesn't work on TIO, but works fine on my coputer

Answer (score 1):

## [ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/), 52 bytes

```
a
known knowns
.
,t1
2s/ k/ unk/
,t2
3,4s/^k/unk/
w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S035/z@RKzsvvzxPAUwWc@lx6ZQYchkV6ytk6yuU5mXrA/lGXMY6JsX6cdn6YIFyrv//AQ)

Answer (score 1):

### **Python 3, 69 bytes**

```
k=['known','unknown']
for i in range(4):print(k[i//2]+' '+k[i%2]+'s')
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: thanks @AdmBorkBork !

Answer (score 1):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), 58 bytes

```
((:^)(s
)( )(known):(un)~*):^!:S~SSS^~S~SSS^S~SSS^~!:S~SSS
```

Uses a simple lookup table with a lot of `S`s.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fQ8MqTlOjmEtTQ0FTIzsvvzxP00qjNE@zTkvTKk7RKrguODg4rg5CQTlQ0f//AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 46 bytes

```
Outer[Print[#,a=nown," ",#2,a,s]&,b={k,unk},b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/9@/tCS1KDqgKDOvJFpZJ9E2L788T0dJQUlH2UgnUac4Vk0nybY6W6c0L7tWJyn2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 39 bytes

```
-(i){||un}known {&|un}knowns
{i<10:->i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/q@vxZWdl1@epwAmi6Gc0jwoF8pQQOPC5bX0/@tqZGpW19SU5tVC5KrV4OxirupMG0MDK127zNr//wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 55 bytes

```matlab
[{'un','known',[115,10],32}{'bdbcbdabcabdbcabdabc'-96}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/ulq9NE9dRz07L78cSEcbGprqGBrE6hgb1VarJ6UkJSelJCYlJ4JYiWCmuq6lWW3s//8A)

#### Explanation:

First, we create a cell array with four strings: `un`, `known`, `s\n` and . Then we create a string `bdbcbdabcabdbcabdabc` that becomes the appropriate indices when we subtract 96: `a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4`. We index the cell array using cell indexing `{}`, and concatenate the result using brackets `[]`.

---

The following is one byte *longer* than the output itself.

```matlab
printf(strrep(', ,s\n, un,s\nun, ,s\nun, un,s',',','known'))
```

Answer (score 0):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula, 78 bytes

```
@ReplaceSubstring("a as,a bas,ba as,ba bas";"a":"b":",";"known":"un":@Newline)
```

Not the shortest but actually shorter than just hard coding the strings in @Formula.

Formula language allows lists as the `from` and `to` parameters to `@ReplaceSubstring`. Just a shame that `@ReplaceSubstring` itself costs 17 bytes and `@Newline` costs 4 more than `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 78 bytes

```
@set a=known
@echo %a% %a%s&echo %a% un%a%s&echo un%a% %a%s&echo un%a% un%a%s
```

Quite hard to golf, everything non-trivial I tried so far just makes it longer.

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 25 bytes

Two solutions, both 25 bytes

```
2iunknowns |exÄwxxäj2xj.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3yizNC87L788r1hBuia14nBLeUXF4SVZRhVZev//AwA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 3269 756e 6b6e 6f77 6e73 201b 7c65 78c4  2iunknowns .|ex.
00000010: 7778 78e4 6a32 786a 2e                   wxx.j2xj.
```

And

```
2iunknown Äwxxäj2xj.Î$rs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3yizNC87L788T0H6cEt5RcXhJVlGFVl6h/tUior//wcA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 3269 756e 6b6e 6f77 6e20 1bc4 7778 78e4  2iunknown ..wxx.
00000010: 6a32 786a 2ece 2472 73                   j2xj..$rs
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 39 bytes

```
echo@;@,"1//' s'|.@;"0/(;'un',])'known'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I9/B2kFHyVBfX12hWL1Gz8FayUBfw1q9NE9dJ1ZTPTsvvzxP/f9/AA)

Here's another one, that I'll explain instead (53 chars):

```
;"1((<<<2)&{,],48&A.,:n)({.,' ';n=.'un';])'known';'s'
```

|

```
                        ({.,' ';n=.'un';])'known';'s'
```

Yields `["known", " ", "un", "known", "s"]` and defines `n` that adds "un" in front. Then for each of the 4 lines respectively we

```
    (<<<2)&{                     Remove "un", the 2nd string
             ]                   Do nothing
               48&A.             Move "un" to the front
                      n          Add "un"
;"1                              Smash the lines.
```

2,0,1,3,4 is #48 in the alphabetically sorted list of permutations of 0,1,2,3,4. I've no idea how it's implemented.

Comment: The permutations is ordered by the permutation/factorial base of the input number 48, I suppose

Comment: Also, as it stands, this is neither a full program (which would use echo) or a function/verb. Adding echo to the beginning of your program or somehow make this tacit would fix this

Comment: @Conor O'Brien oh, fair enough

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 28 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [hakr14](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78186/hakr14).

```
jm+j;d\s^_c"unknown known"d2
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%2Bj%3Bd%5Cs%5E_c.%22+w%0FR%C3%A3%C3%A2%0B%C3%BF7%C2%A8%C3%A27%C3%B6%22d2&debug=0)**

Comment: You can save a byte by [just using a normal string](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%2Bj%3Bd%5Cs%5E_c%22unknown+known%22d2&debug=0).

Comment: whoops, another byte to save: `_c"unknown known"d`=>`c"known unknown"d`

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 35 bytes

```
/2/un1//1/known/1 1s
1 2s
2 1s
2 2s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X99IvzTPUF/fUD87L788T99QwbCYy1DBqJjLCMQyArL@/wcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 41 bytes

**Solution:**

```
(1_',/x,/:\:x:(" known";" unknown")),'"s"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X8MwXl1Hv0JH3yrGqsJKQ0khOy@/PE/JWkmhNA/C1NTUUVcqVvr/HwA)

**Explanation:**

This still feels clunky, but this is the shortest version yet:

```
(1_',/x,/:\:x:(" known";" unknown")),'"s" / the solution
(                                  ),'"s" / append "s" to each left
              (" known";" unknown")       / 2-item list of " known" and " unknown"
            x:                            / save as variable x
      x,/:\:                              / x concatenate each right (/:) with each left (\:)
    ,/                                    / flatten lists
 1_'                                      / drop first item from each list (ie drop the leading whitespace)
```

**Notes:**

Other versions:

```
/ 49 bytes, just join each right/each left and flatten
,/("known";"unknown"),/:\:(" knowns";" unknowns") 

/ 43 bytes, try to be smarter building the known/knowns
,/2 0_/:\:"unknown ",/:("";"un"),\:"knowns"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-R`, 22 bytes

```
`kÍ5 unkÍ5`¸
ïUm+'s)m¸
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YGvNNSB1bmvNNWC4Cu9VbSsncyltuA==&input=LVI=)

Comment: That `-R` in the input should be included in your code length.

Comment: @StephenLeppik, [not any more](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/58974)

Comment: Ah, haven't been paying enough attention to Meta then :/ sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 24 bytes

```
jm+j;d\s^_>B"unknown"2 2
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%2Bj%3Bd%5Cs%5E_%3EB%22unknown%222%202&debug=0).

```
jm+j;d\s^_>B"unknown"2 2   
            "unknown"      String literal
          >          2     Remove the first two letters
           B               Pair the above with the original string - ["unknown", "known"]
         _                 Reverse
        ^              2   Cartesian product with itself
 m                         Map each pair, as d, using:
   j;d                       Join on spaces
  +   \s                     Append "s"
j                          Join on newlines, implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

### Burlesque - 29 bytes

```
"unknown"J2.-CLJcp{wd's_+}muQ

"unknown"J                     duplicate
          2.-                  drop 2
             CL                collect stack
               J               duplicate
                cp             cross product
                  {            begin block
                   wd          words
                     's_+      append `s`
                         }     end block
                          mu   map unlines
                            Q  pretty print
```

[Try it online.](http://cheap.int-e.eu/~burlesque/burlesque.cgi?q=%22unknown%22J2.-CLJcp%7Bwd%27s_%2B%7DmuQ)

*Alternate versions*:

```
"known unknown"wdJcp{wd's_+}muQ
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>23</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
4♀*(╦_╢Ñ▌]■{ u's+p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9tYXRoZ29sZv//NOKZgCoo4pWmX@KVosOR4paMXeKWoHsgdSdzK3D//w)

### Explanation

I really need some base-250 integers

```
4♀*(                 Push 4, push 100, multiply, decrement (resulting in 399)
    ╦                Fetch dictionary word with index 399
     _               Duplicate
      ╢Ñ             Push "un"
        ▌            Prepend to TOS
         ]           Wrap stack in array
          ■          Cartesian product with itself
           {         For-each
             u       Join with space (space character is before the "u")
              's+    Add "s"
                 p   Print
```

Comment: I was thinking [using `n`](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9tYXRoZ29sZv//NOKZgCoo4pWmX@KVosOR4paMXeKWoHsgdSdzbv//), but it seems to just print the newlines?

Comment: @JoKing I'm not completely satisfied with my `n` implementation. For a list, it joins it with newlines, but otherwise it just outputs a newline with python's `print`. That makes it behave strangely in for loops.

Comment: Ah, I had assumed that it added a newline character to the stack

Comment: @JoKing That's probably what I'll change it to, I'll just have to make sure that it doesn't break any unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 78 bytes

This is my first-ever attempt at solving a code golf, so all suggestions welcome!

```js
console.log(k=(u="unknown").substr(2),k+(s="s")+(n="\n")+k,u+s+n+u,k+s+n+u,u+s)
```

#### Explanation

Step 1: `k=(u="unknown").substr(2)`. The `u="unknown"` evaluates to "unknown". A substring of this, from char #2 until the end of the string, is then assigned to variable `k`. This whole thing evaulutes to the outermost assignment, "known", which is the first parameter to `console.log`.

Step 2: Next is a `,`. Each parameter to `console.log` is printed with a space in between, so a `,` represents a space in the output. The current output is "known ".

Step 3: `k+(s="s")` evalutates to "knowns", and at the same time assigns "s" to the variable `s`, to be used as a shorthand for later. The current output is "known knowns"

Step 4: `+(n="\n")+k`. We append a newline to this, and store the newline character as a shorthand for later. We also append `k`. The current output is "known knowns{newline}known".

Step 5: `,u+s+n+u,k+s+n+u,u+s)` the rest is very simple: just appending `k`, `s`, and `u`, using `,`s for spaces, to spell out the rest of the output.

Like I said, this is my first-ever code  golf, so I would appreciate any tips/tricks.

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), <s>62</s> 61 bytes

```
g({s='known'})=>"$s $s\s\n$s un$s\s\nun$s $s\s\nun$s un$s\s";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0ksKvn/P12juthWPTsvvzxPvVbT1k5JpVhBpTimOCYPyCjNgzBBtAISEyKuZP0/NzEzT0OzmktBoaAoM69EI11DU9Oaq/Y/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
┬τj%7↕▬α0▄╘δ₧▲\
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=c2e76a25371216e030dcd4eb9e1e5c&i=&a=1&m=2)

- Split compressed string "known unknown"
- Self Cross-product to produce all pairs
- For each, join with space, and append "s".

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 57 bytes

```
StringReplace["K Ks
K unKs
unK Ks
unK unKs","K"->"known"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@4pCgzLz0otSAnMTk1WslbwbuYy1uhNA9IAQkFKAXiK@koeSvp2ill5@WX5ynF/v//X7cAqLcEAA)

Comment: hehehe... unk :D

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 15 bytes, (@lyxal)

```
`»² ¢λ`⌈:ẊvṄ\s+
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%60%C2%BB%C2%B2%20%C2%A2%CE%BB%60%E2%8C%88%3A%E1%BA%8Av%E1%B9%84%5Cs%2B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 18 bytes

```
`»²`:‛unp":\svpẊvṄ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%60%C2%BB%C2%B2%60%3A%E2%80%9Bunp%22%3A%5Csvp%E1%BA%8Av%E1%B9%84&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Vyxal has really improved my productivity, I wrote this in just 2 minutes.

```
`»²`    Dictionary compressed string "known"
:         Duplicate ^
‛un     Two byte string `un`
p         Prepend un to known    
"          Pair the two words as a list
:          Duplicate ^
\s       Single byte char "s"
vp       Vectorised append to the duplicated lost
Ẋ         Take cartesian product of two lists
vṄ      Vectorised join by space in each ordered pair of the ^
            (Implicit join with newlines, by j flag)
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%60%C2%BB%C2%B2%20%C2%A2%CE%BB%60%E2%8C%88%3A%E1%BA%8Av%E1%B9%84%5Cs%2B&inputs=&header=&footer=) for 15

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 27 bytes

```bash
>{,un}known\ {,un}knowns
ls
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuha77ap1SvNqs_Pyy_NiFBDsYq6cYogKqEKYBgA)

Or, a slightly cheaty version which
[outputs to a file](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2453) called `known knowns`:

### [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 26 bytes

```bash
ls>{,un}known\ {,un}knowns
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuha7cortqnVK82qz8_LL82IUEOxiiIKNyYklClBJZHGYAQA)