# Text compression

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

With the given text below, there are some words in the text that repeats several times in the text. Use any programming language to write a short code that compresses the text to display it. Or in other words, use the smallest number of bytes to display the text.
The Text is:

```
Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.
A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked.
If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers,
Where's the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?
```

Comment: I'm honestly surprised this didn't get closed as a dupe of that Rick-Roll question. Are we not doing that anymore?

Comment: @JoKing it *is* a different string. A little variety on the same challenge can be fun sometimes.

Comment: @moonheart08 pretty sure that point was shot down in meta.

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 106 bytes

```r
"["=gsub
cat(1["Peter Piper picked",2[" peck of pickled peppers","1 a2.
A2 1.
If 1 a2,
Where's the2 1?"]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxCoAgFEV3v@LxlgpE0D2isa2tQRpKnxUFidr3m7UcOOfekDNqbLf4rMwsqZYaR0oUYDx8oT/MSRa50giezAm3@9tFtrgvl4gcJSxKsF6BFGxw8Cln006BqghppzJ0OM9Nzi8)

Comment: That is a very clever use of aliasing!!

Comment: Great solution ! It beats also the memCompress approach [47+79=126 bytes](https://tio.run/##lY49a8MwEIZ3/YpDFGQZ4aFLaSGUfizdMgS6ZLnY5/iILQudQmj/vHtJ26l0CIgDvS/33JMXXNk1Fcqw5qQzcXugDhAStQeY@0swapIoaS@Nefqvgr@cxrz1cA0@mPeBMjmBMtAVhx6tOWUu9Myxmmh6maeUSaRCHxw6b0yLpbJ1XcNmYAF9CLfQ80ggx93EIjzHRksC7Dou@sMRdh@FBLojQZmBYzqW75WIk9ooGDATPIANl7zh2M@VRetvhD8pgPsh6F0X3DZuowtCaWWtX85CavpK7a9rJuzO/soNLuPJhbt71d@7sPF@Wb4A "R – Try It Online")

Comment: This idea saved me another byte [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145440/67312) as well!

Comment: Wow, I didn't spot that golf. That's really nice.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>80 73 72 68 67 61</s>  57 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“¡ŀṪ]ṃ{yṁ“Ñ3$ṘW5Ḍż⁸¢Hŀ“³ḌM“¡FỊİg“ÑɲʋØƥþƈƘ}“ṣɠ»“Ƙ9~ḷ’ṃFḊ”?
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDC482PNy5Kvbhzubqyoc7G4FChycaqzzcOSPc9OGOnqN7HjXuOLTI42gDSO1moIgvWJPbw91dRzakg1Wf3HSq@/CMY0sP7zvWcWxGLVDs4c7FJxcc2g1kHZthWfdwx/ZHDTOBFrg93NH1qGGu/f//AA)**

#### How?

```
“...“...“...“...“...“...»“Ƙ9~ḷ’ṃFḊ”? - Main Link: no arguments
“...“...“...“...“...“...»            - list of compressed strings
                                     -   = [" Peter Piper picked",
                                     -      " peck of pickled peppers",
                                     -      ".\nA",
                                     -      ".\nIf",
                                     -      ",\nWhere's the",
                                     -      " a"]
                         “Ƙ9~ḷ’      - base 250 literal X = 2331781969
                               ṃ     - base decompress - i.e. use the list of strings as if
                                     -   they were the digits [1,2,3,4,5,0]
                                     -   X in base 6 is [1,0,2,3,2,1,4,1,0,2,5,2,1], so:
                                     -   [" Peter Piper picked",
                                     -    " a",
                                     -    " peck of pickled peppers",
                                     -    ".\nA"," peck of pickled peppers",
                                     -    " Peter Piper picked",
                                     -    ".\nIf",
                                     -    " Peter Piper picked",
                                     -    " a",
                                     -    " peck of pickled peppers",
                                     -    ",\nWhere's the",
                                     -    " peck of pickled peppers",
                                     -    " Peter Piper picked"]
                                F    - flatten
                                 Ḋ   - dequeue (remove the leading space)
                                  ”? - literal '?' character (causes print of previous)
                                     - implicit print (of the '?' character)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 114 bytes

```javascript
print(`0 a1.
A1 0.
If 0 a1,
Where's the1 0?`.replace(/\d/g,n=>+n?' peck of pickled peppers':'Peter Piper picked'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcm9DoIwFAbQnae4WyEiP6uJEkc3NhcHmvZDKlBubhsTn76i48l56bcORhzHY2BnIevmZ3xSYnE@5kNDuq2ya0tNld1G@rHM7hMEKlCcsEc3VAJetEFeP2z9LP35cvCdIoaZaRuJnZkX2N3MkKBOqkeEUO92/hdWFUVKXw)

I would claim this answer is from [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs), anyway, 19 bytes saved.

Thanks [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld), saves 3 bytes.

Comment: [114 bytes](https://tio.run/##Hcm9DoIwFAbQnae4WyEiP6uJEkc3NhcHmvZDKlBubhsTn76i48l56bcORhzHY2BnIevmZ3xSYnE@5kNDuq2ya0tNld1G@rHM7hMEKlCcsEc3VAJetEFeP2z9LP35cvCdIoaZaRuJnZkX2N3MkKBOqkeEUO92/hdWFUVKXw).

Answer (score 5):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), <s>73</s> 71 bytes

```
00000000: 0b48 2d49 2d52 08c8 2c00 9205 99c9 d9a9  .H-I-R..,.......
00000010: 290a 890a 05a9 c9d9 0af9 6960 819c d414  ).........i`....
00000020: 20bf 0028 5fac c7e5 884b 4a01 d31c 3d2e   ..(_....KJ...=.
00000030: cf34 0552 8cd7 e10a cf48 2d4a 552f 5628  .4.R.....H-JU/V(
00000040: c948 25c1 227b 00                        .H%."{.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BSwQxDIXv/oqHIKzgxLTTzjSC93G9LehV23S6CHrckz9@zDi74MV3eKQl@fJSTqV8zsfT17LwWQ/gEhJ8DWIWPTipPZUZ4jlCRAVVsgA0dU/dgeiONl1tBGcML5yRVuNorSpVwLkJBhkYyYmiBheAW7ro4/0Pw68MLg1WJsSWFTrOESmFgpDZofZO0Vc/w4LQ7m0dft6bPV4YvTG09cEi2BlJ64jZWSJt230Z9t8QB9sACnT4jTF1@5f7192ZEVaGrP1RHbwfiyXCP6Lphq6/aVl@AA)

Comment: How did you shave off bytes of a bubblegum answer?

Comment: @Laikoni the original 73 bytes answer was created using `gzip` on the highest compression level (`-9`) plus some metadata shaving using `head` and `tail`, the 71 byter is generated using zopfli, which I initially forgot about. Zopfli usually creates shorter DEFLATE streams.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried up to 5,000,000 iterations on zopfli, it couldn't find anything past the 71-byte one on iteration 3109.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>64</s> <s>60</s> <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```
“¡ŀṪ]ṃ{yṁ“Ñ3$ṘW5Ḍż⁸¢Hŀ»j⁾ a,Ṛẋ2ż“³ḌM“¡FỊİg“ÑɲʋØƥþƈƘ}»FḊ”?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDC482PNy5Kvbhzubqyoc7G4FChycaqzzcOSPc9OGOnqN7HjXuOLTI42jDod1Zjxr3KSTqPNw56@GubiOgDFD3ZqAaX7Axbg93dx3ZkA7Wf3LTqe7DM44tPbzvWMexGbWHdrs93NH1qGGu/f//AA)

Comment: Wow, surprisingly similar to another answer, with the same language and same byte count. I don't actually know what's happening in this language, so is the code basicically the same?

Comment: A lot of the overlap in the code is the identical compressed strings, which is not surprising.

Comment: @tox the two programs are currently not working in the same way (although both of us have used similar ideas as each other in the history of revisions). This one is using compressed string lists (`“...“...»`) to form most of the four lines and then interleaving (`ż`) with the less repetitive parts (like `',\nIf'`), again with compressed string lists; you can see how mine works from the description.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 115 bytes

```python
a="Peter Piper picked"
b=" peck of pickled peppers"
print a,"a%s.\nA"%b+b,a+".\nIf",a,"a%s,\nWhere's the"%b+b,a+"?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9FWKSC1JLVIISCzAEgWZCZnp6YocSXZKikUpCZnK@SngcVyUlOA/AKgkmIlroKizLwShUQdpUTVYr2YPEcl1STtJJ1EbSUgxzNNSQcioxOTF56RWpSqXqxQkpEKV2Ov9P8/AA)

Prints multiple commas-separated strings to put spaces in between them.

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 115 bytes

```python
print("1 a2.\nA2 1.\nIf 1 a2,\nWhere's the2 1?".translate({49:"Peter Piper picked",50:" peck of pickled peppers"}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8lQIdFILybP0UjBEEh5pimABHRi8sIzUotS1YsVSjJSgVL2SnolRYl5xTmJJaka1SaWVkoBqSWpRQoBmQVAsiAzOTs1RUnH1MBKSaEgNTlbIT8NLJiTmgLkFwDVFCvVamr@/w8A)

Python 3's `translate` does the heavy lifting. Using non-printable characters with single-digit ASCII value should save two bytes.

Comment: `exit` saves 1 byte for the Python 3 program.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 99

- 4 bytes saved thanks to @manatwork.

```bash
echo "${P=Peter Piper picked} a${p= peck of pickled peppers}.
A$p $P.
If $P a$p,
Where's the$p $P?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCoAgFET3nuITQpvoBhIt27lrXTqiGPRJd9HZ7eNmhnnzzqPE1uDiTYN@rbGoeMgmluTkMvxHh37ZEMNlukOnF7xsFql8s1o1k7az2oKU2DypPeLBWKhG9HMZWvsB)

Comment: You could move the variable declarations to their first usages with assign default value parameter expansions:  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCoAgFET3nuITQpvoBhIt27lrXTqiGPRJd9HZ7eNmhnnzzqPE1uDiTYN@rbGoeMgmluTkMvxHh37ZEMNlukOnF7xsFql8s1o1k7az2oKU2DypPeLBWKhG9HMZWvsB "Bash – Try It Online").

Comment: @manatwork Wow, I had no idea you could do that.  Pretty cool to get under 100 - Thanks!  This technique would make a [good bash tips answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash).

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>99</s> 87 bytes

<sup>-12 bytes: turns out 2 substitutions are shorter which is basically the same as everyone else's solution (except Bubblegum?)</sup>

```
i1 a0.
A0 1.
If 1 a0,
Where's the0 1?Í0/ peck of pickled peppers
Í1/Peter Piper picked
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9NQIdFAj8vRQMFQj8szTQHE1eEKz0gtSlUvVijJSAVK2Esf7jXQVyhITc5WyE9TKMhMzs5JTQHyCwpSi4q5Dvca6geklqQWKQRkAgXA8qkp//8DAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 123 bytes

```java
v->"".format("%s a%s.%nA%2$s %1$s.%nIf %1$s a%2$s,%nWhere's the%2$s %1$s?","Peter Piper picked"," peck of pickled peppers")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BSwMxEIXv@yuG0OCubAN6rVa8CB6EQkEP4iFmkza72SQkk4Ui/e3rdC1eZua99zG8Xk5y3XfDbMcYEkJPWhS0TpjiFdrgxe2miuXbWQXKyZzhTVoPPxXA1c0okdYUbAcjZfUek/WHzy@Q6ZCbBQV4ub57eCeu/UO2YOBxntZbxoQJaZRYM55B8iy4f@b3qwz8bnURr2a5KCKz5f7jqJO@yYBH/Y89sZbtNOoEOxtpRqsG3ZEJUasBglkcpzvSkYDMmnmzdNufMupRhIIiUi@sjZAxulPti3NNc4HO1Xn@BQ)

Comment: Are you allowed to take a required argument like that?

Comment: @Quintec [Yes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12696/76162), if the input is unused

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>120</s> <s>117</s> 116 bytes

```python
a,b="Peter Piper picked"," peck of pickled peppers"
exit(f"{a} a{b}.\nA{b} {a}.\nIf {a} a{b},\nWhere's the{b} {a}?")
```

[Format strings](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1EnyVYpILUktUghILMASBZkJmenpijpKCkUpCZnK@SngUVyUlOA/AKggmIlrtSKzBKNNKXqxFqFxOqkWr2YPEcgpQDkA5meaQowCZ2YvPCM1KJU9WKFkoxUqBJ7Jc3//wE) were shorter than [addition(129 bytes)](https://tio.run/##RYqxDoMwDER3vsLy4qJULJ1RxcjmrUuWKhglogpWyMLXp1EYWE7v7p6e2e/xVQqPyJIlAQetqcFtsmCnI4KK22Bf2/aTpXatylHPFGJ@sCH4klFDg41TAyDDrc7rhZeATxs/XpLQAdkL3uqb@lL@) and a [join(140 bytes)](https://tio.run/##RYqxDsIwDER3vsLy4laKujBXiJHNGwNlQK2rhCLHSrPw9SFKB5bTu7tn3@yjnkvhEVmyJOBgNS3Mmyx4shHBZN4grm37yFK7VWWvZwqaO6LhHYN2D3YEL3LmaJj02gDIcau39cBDQDfp3UsS2iF7wb96oWffl/ID).

-3 thanks to Jo King,
-1 thanks to Jonathan Allen

Comment: That's not a format string. [*That's*](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1EnyVYpILUktUghILMASBZkJmenpijpKCkUpCZnK@SngUVyUlOA/AKggmIlroKizLwSjTSl6sRahcTqpFq9mDxHIKUA5AOZnmkKMAmdmLzwjNSiVPVihZKMVKgSeyXN//8B) a format string. (117 bytes)

Comment: [Programs may output to STDERR](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2451/53748), so save 1 by replacing `print` with `exit`.

Answer (score 2):

## Twig, 105 bytes

This uses a simple replacement to fill in the gaps.

Twig's `replace()` filter allows you to define the values to replace as the keys of an hash.
Luckly, it also works with arrays, as they have numerical keys.

```
{{"0a1.
A1 0.
If 0 a1,
Where's the1 0?"|replace(["Peter Piper picked"," peck of pickled peppers"])|raw}}
```

The `|raw` is needed to avoid escaping, which turned `Where's` into `Where&#039;s`.

You can try it on https://twigfiddle.com/phqpts

---

Since this is compiled down to PHP, the equivalent for PHP would be:

```php
<?php
    $array = array("Peter Piper picked", " peck of pickled peppers");
    $string = "0 a1.
A1 0.
If 0 a1,
Where's the1 0?";
    
    echo str_replace(array_keys($array), $array, $string);
```

Which can be shortened significatively.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 104 bytes

```ruby
/ a/=~$a="Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers"
puts"#$a.
A#$' #$`.
If #$a,
Where's the#$' #$`?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYmxCoAgFAB3v@KhgkvkF0Q0trW19qoXiUEPtaGlXzeJlju4C9d852wBbfNobORAiQIMjgvZLZ5WQGBaPJzbF45SmLj8KAVfKUqlsRad0gaUnmrRb8VYiXGnQCZC2ul/rcz5BQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>101</s> 100 bytes

```
s/^/0 a1.\nA1 0.\nIf 0 a1,\nWhere's the1 0?/
s/0/Peter Piper picked/g
s/1/ peck of pickled peppers/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxDkBAEER7X7GdBnv3BaLU6TQiETeOkHOxfP9ZmpnMeyNwpQ9PSsIjG5psNYTGktFqF/pAMYR@xYVc6F6hquZM2HCHGxd1W9SM27zDsVdhmSLmnc7lpwec7qgnYZ/SCw)

-1 byte thanks to @DigitalTrauma

Comment: Replace `.*` with `^` to save a byte

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 86 bytes

```
/1/Peter Piper picked//2/ peck of pickled peppers/1 a2.
A2 1.
If 1 a2,
Where's the2 1?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxDoAgEAR7XnGdjfECHzCWdnTWBJZANJF4/B9Pm0lmduUKUiBjsGWPjod8bcpW44nE7Jga4kl3/tOFpN70IWwpuMVsjuxi9kyfzuYoeDAJ9QId1jFe)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 123 bytes

```c
f(){printf("%s a%s.\nA%2$s %1$s.\nIf %1$s a%2$s,\nWhere's the%2$s %1$s?","Peter Piper picked"," peck of pickled peppers");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0m1WCFRtVgvJs9R1UilWEHVUAXE8UwDs4BSQEGdmLzwjNSiVPVihZKMVLgyeyUdpYDUktQihYDMAiBZkJmcnZoCFFQoSE3OVshPA4vkpKYA@QVABcVKmta1/4G2KuQmZuZpaHJVc3ECXWLNVfsfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 166 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Text;f="peck of pickled";g="picked";u="peppers";p="Peter Piper";s=join" "[p,g,"a",f,u+".\nA",f,u,p,g+".\nIf",p,g,"a",f,u+",\nWhere's","the",f,u,p,g+"?"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY69CsIwFIVfJdzFwasvUIoIOggOBQUHdQjpTY3NH0kq@vLGtC66fec7ZzhCE7fZuHbQxAxXNivjXUjskNqtfeCRnqmSNXgSPXOSeSV6TS1UXXGFRxzG2nsKESpfQ0OJAmtUEVDF@u6UBQZnjx0CB5Q4zGF5sesJsegp7iTg3wQv9nSjQLMICOlGP/MVXPMh8fKyZjG/hdS8i3mx2@fNy3KjxDc0mifpgvkA)

Answer (score 1):

## jq, 110 characters

(106 characters code + 4 characters command line options)

```
"1 a2.
A2 1.
If 1 a2,
Where's the2 1?"|gsub("1";"Peter Piper picked")|gsub("2";" peck of pickled peppers")
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -nr '"1 a2.
A2 1.
If 1 a2,
Where'"'"'s the2 1?"|gsub("1";"Peter Piper picked")|gsub("2";" peck of pickled peppers")'
Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.
A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked.
If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers,
Where's the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/1/JUCHRSI/L0UjBUI/LM00BxNXhCs9ILUpVL1YoyUgFStgr1aQXlyZpKBkqWSsFpJakFikEZBYAyYLM5OzUFCVNqLQRUFqhIDU5WyE/DSyXk5oC5BcAlRYraf7//183rwgA)

Answer (score 1):

## SQL Server, 211

```
declare @a char(18)='Peter Piper picked'
declare @b char(24)=' peck of pickled peppers'
declare @c char=char(10)
print @a+' a'+@b+'.'+@c+'A'+@b+' '+@a+'.'+@c+'If '+@a+' a'+@b+','+@c+'Where''s the'+@b+' '+@a+'?'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aa49cadbe030dbd774f61739617e7400)

Comment: Nice solution! A few ways to improve: for multiple variables use a comma instead of restating `declare`; use an actual line break in the string instead of `char(10)`, in fact you can put the line breaks directly in the `print` statement and eliminate `@c` entirely. Pick your most-used variable and use `@` by itself (its valid!)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 137 bytes

```sql
SELECT p+a+k+'.
A'+k+' '+p+'.
If '+p+a+k+',
Where''s the'+k+' '+p+'?'
FROM(SELECT'Peter Piper picked'p,' a'a,' peck of pickled peppers'k)b
```

That last return before the `FROM` is for readability only, the rest are part of the string concatenation.

Different method than [SeanC's SQL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174066/70172).

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>60</s> 56 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╣lF╤╨┴+Y╟W╪▄,○F«↑•L°T»`┼◄ü√}x![Ñ$Θ☼²qσQ¼▬ôZ¡▄╙╥⌂å╛►¶▓&╗s
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b96c46d1d0c12b59c757d8dc2c0946ae18074cf854af60c51181fb7d78215ba524e90ffd71e551ac16935aaddcd3d27f86be1014b226bb73&i=&a=1)

Comment: [Here's](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=809abd60863d514c65cdb9865c15a7d15e020a968b26bca7d1eb048e3f6804adde47eecd1a1c32362b5fec18d7eb912669dc25f1a12f4480&i=&a=1) one byte shorter unpacked, and [this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b96c46d1d0c12b59c757d8dc2c0946ae18074cf854af60c51181fb74640c38df7a6778fa482529ed9337762ff26f3532bdccb705736e7e78&i=&a=1) seems to be making a profound statement about existence.

Comment: `"i am.  Am i.  If i am,  Where's them i?"`  I can't stop laughing.  This is gold.

Comment: Descartes ain't not nothin' on me.

Answer (score 1):

### Windows Batch, 179 bytes

```
4D534346000000009C00000000000000
2C000000000000000301010001000000
000000004200000001000100DF000000
000000000000544DB5682000612E6261
7400E59D45D15200DF00434B73484DCE
C85708482D492D5208C82C00920599C9
D9A9290A890A05A9C9D90AF96960811C
A048416A0150BE588F970BA2C911970A
2CC6C13579A69164990E4C5F78466A51
AA7AB14249462A09D6DA0300

extract %0 .bat
.bat
```

Self-extracting Cabinet file using Batch/CAB polyglot.
The blank line is needed for the batch file processor to find the actual batch code, but can be LF alone instead of CR/LF.
The Cabinet file is just a series of "@echo <string>" lines, and the '@' symbol suppresses the "echo" itself from being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 150 bytes

```
var s="Peter Piper picked"
var z=" peck of pickled peppers"
var v=s+" a"+z
var x=z+" "+s
print(v+".\n"+"A"+x+".\n"+"If "+v+",\n"+"Where's the "+x+"?")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BDoIwEEX3nGIyGyE1HsBYDUt3JC7cuGlggAYszbQSxHj2Wmvc/Myb/5I/TH7UJrQPA3elTa64c3somdXzcPGsTXcs4BVmxeAkVuSJodI2ptX1QA1m32qVCJbqAaY2/UdqItuouZ8wSycQFIo14SLXiChcZuOEz2eBu5tBgSWK5X@f22jEZpvo2hPTxoHvCZJ0wiK8wwc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 85 bytes

```
1 a0.¶A0 1.¶If 1 a0,¶Where's the0 1?
1
Peter Piper picked
0
 peck of pickled peppers
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy1Ah0UDv0DZHAwVDIOWZpgAS0Dm0LTwjtShVvVihJCMVKGXPZcgVkFqSWqQQkFkAJAsyk7NTU7gMuBQKUpOzFfLTwCI5qSlAfgFQQfH//wA) Same idea as everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 107 bytes

```php
<?=($a="Peter Piper picked")." a".($b=" peck of pickled peppers").".
A$b $a.
If $a a$b,
Where's the$b $a?";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCoAgEEX3nmIYBioIL1ASLdu5a601oRg0lPc3a/Mfn/ckSCnjZFpyBi1nvsFGqStxS7xjpxEc6pa8QRDeElzH707e65eaPl@k1UweyGm1HBXgyPdqDXxz80AO/MsJh1Je)

Comment: Missing a point in the first line.

Comment: Use comma instead of concatenation to save 4 bytes: `<?=$a=...," a",$b=...,...`

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 116 bytes

```
prin rejoin[a:"Peter Piper picked"" a"b:" peck of pickled peppers"".^/A"b" "a".^/If "a" a"b",^/Where's the"b" "a"?"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYuxCoNAEER/ZZnGJsTeJqRMJzYWonB6I54GXVb//7wLaYY3wxujjw1910e1sItxPcLeuQo1L5rUQVNqmDZ6QBzGCqKcNjnm3/ylT12TdQLPoXxjhMBl/MwZ8gePoWwXGotTroV/5YU@xhs)

### Explanation:

The job is done by the `rejoin` funcion, which reduces and joins a block of values.

```
prin rejoin [                      ; print the reduced (evaluated) and joined block
    a: "Peter Piper picked"        ; save the text to a
    " a"                           ; literal " a"
    b: " peck of pickled peppers"  ; save the text to b
    ".^/A"                         ; literal newline followed by "A"
    b                              ; " peck of pickled peppers" 
    " "                            ; literal " "
    a                              ; "Peter Piper picked"
    ".^/If "                       ; literal ".^/If "
    a                              ; "Peter Piper picked"
    " a"                           ; literal " a"
    b                              ; " peck of pickled peppers" 
    ",^/Where's the"               ; literal "," folowwed by a newline by "Where's the"  
    b                              ; " peck of pickled peppers"      
    " "                            ; literal " "
    a                              ; "Peter Piper picked" 
    "?"                            ; literal "?"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 121 bytes

```
echo('1 a2.',CR,'A2 1.',CR,'If 1 a2,',CR,'Where''s the2 1?')rplc('1';'Peter Piper picked';'2';' peck of pickled peppers')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUs9C4MwFPwrb7sGgmDWDqU4uUkX5xJPYhV8RP9/fFqHO@7zVwpjWh@o5Rsq@Obj8Q5S37Id5Sz83/WJmcAme6JtXnBZl2hfPNFxZ5ZuUmOd4szBwmAQZZxlHa904WBebbTBlXIA)

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, <s>99</s> 101 bytes

```
$a='Peter Piper picked'
$b=' peck of pickled peppers'
"$a a$b.
A$b $a.
If $a a$b,
Where's the$b $a`?"
```

Comment: Shouldn't $a='Peter Piper picked' ?

Comment: It appears as though the space in `the $b` makes your submission both longer and invalid ([TIO](https://tio.run/##JYoxCoAwEAT7e8UhB9eIPxCxtLOzTnQlYsAjEXx@DNoM7OzY9SDlgBhLEdfrjBuJ58Mq7VhPbErie2XDevK1fzJiq9tqk5UacezEdzSKZ3EdTTv/qqUlIEEz3wH8vUNTygs)).

Comment: Furthermore, I think you are missing a `[...]Peter Piper picked?` at your output's end.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <del>123</del> <del>118</del> 116 bytes

```cs
v=>@"0 a1.
A1 0.
If 0 a1,
Where's the1 0?".Replace("0","Peter Piper picked").Replace("1"," peck of pickled peppers")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9BSwMxEIXv8yuGXNzAGnbPa6tSUASFRQ89h@ysHRqTmEkLUvrb1yiI4uXBx/sO7zm5dDHTchAOr/jyIYXeBvhLZhO9J1c4BjH3FCiz@2c8cngfwHkrguMJpNjCDu8OwV1xKK2UXOU1zitcjqv1jerQ9gZue@wMPMz4hS1sd5TpQrDsqBbXyjxT8tZRozrVqpEKZRw51Uzs9jQp/Wv01cBEbo9x/q49TZVTtUXpZYCfTcfIEz5ZDo2GE2zqpejJbDMXqieomZte6wHOcF4@AQ)

Inspired by @Olivier Grégoire's [java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173965/text-compression/173980#173980)

5 bytes saved by @sebbs

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>78</s> <s>76</s> <s>74</s> 72 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
’0 a1.
A10.
If0 a1,
W€Î's €€10?’TS.•1~¼ ¿•“±æ€‚ ÿÇì“'p0ǝ„íÎ´Œ™„r¾Ð«‚ðì:¦
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcNMA4VEQz0uR0MDPS7PNBBHhyv8UdOaw33qxQpAGogMDeyB6kKC9R41LDKsO7RH4dB@IOtRw5xDGw8vAylpmKVweP/h9sNA1hz1AoPjcx81zDu89nDfoS1HJz1qAaqcV3Ro3@EJh1YDVR7ecHiN1aFl//8DAA)

**Explanation:**

```
’0 a1.
A10.
If0 a1,
W€Î's €€10?’              # String "0 a1.\nA10.\nIf0 a1,\nWhere's the10?"
TS                        # 10 to digits: ["1","0"]
.•1~¼ ¿•                  # String "pickled"
        “±æ€‚ ÿÇì“        # String "neck of ÿ pepper", where the "ÿ" will 
                          # automatically be replaced with the top value of the stack
                  'p0ǝ    # Replace the character at index 0 with a "p":
                          #  "peck of pickled pepper"
„íÎ´Œ                     # String "peter pipe"
     ™                    # Titlecased: "Peter Pipe"
      „r¾Ð                # String "r picked"
          «               # Merge them together: "Peter Piper pickled"
           ‚              # Pair them together:
                          #  ["peck of pickled pepper","Peter Piper pickled"]
             
            ðì            # Prepend a space before each:
                          #  [" peck of pickled pepper"," Peter Piper pickled"]
              :           # Replace the ["1","0"] with this list of strings
               ¦          # Remove the leading space (and output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why:

- `’0 a1.\nA10.\nIf0 a1,\nW€Î's €€10?’` is `"0 a1.\nA10.\nIf0 a1,\nWhere's the10?"`
- `.•1~¼ ¿•` is `"pickled"`
- `“±æ€‚ ÿÇì“` is `"neck of ÿ pepper"`
- `„íÎ´Œ` is `"peter pipe"`
- `„r¾Ð` is `"r picked"`

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 132 bytes

```hs
g x y=x++y++x
p=g"Peter Piper picked"
q=g" peck of pickled peppers"
a=g" ".("a"++).q
f=p(a".\nA"++p".\nIf "++a",\nWhere's the")++"?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrBCoMwEETv@YplL1W2@Aeh9FjoQfDQi5egGyPadE1S0K9PYy/DmzfjTFx4XXOeYIdD70QH0a5ET9hy4gDtLCVlHhYeUW3Fg/CwwMf@5cpj6VI@EZU5V2wqNEhUN5uyWiqDTe/vRcgJDwsFDV57/3Ic@BIhOcaaCG@Y32b2oEG@qUvh6cHmHw)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 102 bytes

Basically just change the repeater words or sentences with numbers, and then apply **php-strtr**

```php
<?=strtr("0 a 1.
A 1 0.
If 0 a 1,
Where's the 1 0?",["Peter Piper picked","peck of pickled peppers"]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcmxCoQwFETRPl8xvEaFIFqvIpZ2dhaLxaIjEQUfSf4/uja3OFedptR0bYg@@lwq/FCXpkeNqjTDhhesmRw9s4Do@F@d2K@MjPQYd32q@3JwFSvK5cC1vXByhVKfH2QuPind)

Or

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 144 bytes

```php
<?=strtr("0 1 25 a 3 of 2l5 4.
A 3 of 2l5 4 0 1 25.
If 0 1 25 a 3 of 2l5 4,
Where's the 3 of 2l5 4 0 1 25?",[Peter,Piper,pick,peck,peppers,ed]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSopEhDyUDBUMHIVCFRwVghP03BKMdUwUSPyxGJpwBRocflmaaARbEOV3hGalGqerFCSUYqpjZ7JZ3ogNSS1CKdgMwCIFmQmZytU5AKJgqAAsU6qSmxmtb//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), <s>146</s> 143 bytes

```
1 P$="Peter Piper picked":Q$=" peck of pickled peppers":PRINT P$" a"Q$".":PRINT"A"Q$" "P$".":PRINT"If "P$" a"Q$",":PRINT"Where's the"Q$" "P$"?"
```

It's not very clever, but it works.

Comment: Saved 3 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/),  <s>124 120</s>  117 bytes

```
f(){var s='Peter Piper picked',t=' peck of pickled peppers';return"$s a$t.\nA$t $s.\nIf $s a$t,\nWhere's the$t $s?";}
```

-4 bytes by declaring both variables on the same row

-3 bytes by adding the leading space to 'peck of pickled peppers'

[Try it on Dartpad!](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/80e3c406231cbed1421ec1276517eaf5)

Answer (score 0):

### Windows Batch, 129 bytes

Alternatively,

```
set a= Peter Piper picked
set b= peck of pickled peppers
@echo%a% a%b%.
@echo A%b%%a%.
@echo If%a% a%b%,
@echo Where's the%b%%a%?
```

Using LF alone instead of CR/LF combinations for line-endings.

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 1446 bytes

```
{{i}dd}c{ii}ic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{iiiii}ddc{ii}iiiiic{i}dddc{d}dc{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{{i}dd}c{d}iiicddddddc{i}ddcddddddcdc{{d}iii}iic{iiiiii}iiiiic{dddddd}dddddc{{i}dd}c{d}dcddc{i}ddc{{d}iii}dddddc{{i}dd}dc{d}ic{{d}iii}c{{i}dd}c{d}iiicddddddc{i}ddcic{d}iiicdc{{d}iii}iic{{i}dd}c{d}dc{i}icc{d}dc{i}iiicic{{d}iii}ic{ddd}ddddddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ddd}dddc{{i}dd}c{d}dcddc{i}ddc{{d}iii}dddddc{{i}dd}dc{d}ic{{d}iii}c{{i}dd}c{d}iiicddddddc{i}ddcic{d}iiicdc{{d}iii}iic{{i}dd}c{d}dc{i}icc{d}dc{i}iiicic{{d}ii}dddc{iiiii}ddc{ii}ic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{iiiii}ddc{ii}iiiiic{i}dddc{d}dc{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{{i}dd}c{d}iiicddddddc{i}ddcddddddcdc{ddddd}ddddc{ddd}ddddddc{iiiiii}iiic{iii}dc{{d}iii}c{iiiii}ddc{ii}ic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{iiiii}ddc{ii}iiiiic{i}dddc{d}dc{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{{i}dd}c{d}iiicddddddc{i}ddcddddddcdc{{d}iii}iic{iiiiii}iiiiic{dddddd}dddddc{{i}dd}c{d}dcddc{i}ddc{{d}iii}dddddc{{i}dd}dc{d}ic{{d}iii}c{{i}dd}c{d}iiicddddddc{i}ddcic{d}iiicdc{{d}iii}iic{{i}dd}c{d}dc{i}icc{d}dc{i}iiicic{{d}iii}dc{ddd}ddddc{{i}dd}dddc{ii}dddcdddc{i}iiic{d}dddc{dddddd}ddc{{i}ddd}iiiiiic{{d}ii}dddc{{i}dd}iiiic{d}ddcdddc{{d}iii}ic{{i}dd}c{d}dcddc{i}ddc{{d}iii}dddddc{{i}dd}dc{d}ic{{d}iii}c{{i}dd}c{d}iiicddddddc{i}ddcic{d}iiicdc{{d}iii}iic{{i}dd}c{d}dc{i}icc{d}dc{i}iiicic{{d}ii}dddc{iiiii}ddc{ii}ic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{iiiii}ddc{ii}iiiiic{i}dddc{d}dc{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{{i}dd}c{d}iiicddddddc{i}ddcddddddcdc{dddd}iiic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VNLDgIhDD2RhzI8jV27JD070g8t6MS4m5lEFgT6eX394XbFnZ6PS2u1EgNcKhFTv5nklIou7cclpXYBiaUYUryGtfyhThsOIwJUgcDtt3/g5uLqAZKInsEmscTZUYbzYqN0KHRfaVBIFyJzMEmrLBkmtrHkgHyjz0dlzvjs544jkI3eqKdDatypNIchf@b5neod0b0@sCSjKq6JpNwelu06WIaU7TCg3Jn/RvyyEapv7QU)